# HighStock: chart gets broken when navigator touches right border

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm developing an web application that handles and shows large amounts of live data from some devices. To visualise the data I decided to use HighStock. It seems to work well on most of the data:

[image: chart 1]

However, when the bottom navigator touches right border, the picture becomes quite different:

[image: chart 2]

The timeline is almost the same, but the number of points is different, also vertical scale is different... What is this happening? How to fix it?

My code looks this way:

```js
const ch1 = Highcharts.stockChart('chart1', {
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1,
        inputEnabled: false,
        buttonTheme: {visibility: 'hidden'},
        labelStyle: {visibility: 'hidden'},
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Metrics',
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Sensor 1', data: [],
    }, {
        name: 'Sensor 2', data: [],
    }, {
        name: 'Sensor 3', data: [],
    }]
});

// a,b,c gets values from the server
// They are arrays of pairs of timestamp & value
ch1.series[0].setData(a);
ch1.series[1].setData(b);
ch1.series[2].setData(c);
// tm_min & tm_max are dynamically calculated using the data
ch1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(tm_min, tm_max);
```

---

**Update:** [Here is an example](https://www.aivanf.com/static/highstock-problem.html) with 2% of my data – try to do the same as shown above.

Comment: It is probably happening because of `series.dataGrouping`: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping. If it doesn't help you, please elaborate with a working demo showing this issue (use sample data with the same structure).

Comment: @WojciechChmiel thanks for your reply! Yeah, I noticed some kind of grouping... Well, I don't want to turn it off (because my data is really large, more than 100 000 points in a single series), but why it behaves so weird exactly at the right border? Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately, It's hard to tell what's going on without a reproduction. Could you prepare it?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I created an example, have a look please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The issue is caused by your data and `xAxis.ordinal` that is enabled by default in Highstock. Your data has many empty points on the right side of the chart and because of ordinal, the empty space was not rendered, yet dataGrouping grouped data differently.

Check this here https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x1tgqbw6/ (disabled ordinal):

```
  xAxis: {
    ordinal: true
  }
```

So, the solution is to disable `xAxis.ordinal` or generate your data without null points:

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ex054oy8/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Comment: Brilliant! I think it would be better to fix the data. But I don't understand, what do you mean saying `empty points`? If a print tail values with `console.log(bytes.slice(len-100, len))` I see existing values. Also, all the values become points getting a timestamp that's calculated with a fixed step (in the row `tm = Math.floor(current.measured + 1000 * i / current.freq)`). I just see nothing empty, so I don't understand the problem reason...

Comment: Check the console result in this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yrdk3s0n/. As you can see there are points like `[1569939691464, undefined]` in the data you are passing to the chart series.

Comment: Got it! Thank you  I just got used to see exceptions when accessing outside an array, so I thought my formula is correct... My bad, I should be more attentive ‍♂️